# Save state of webpage in webview inside fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, webview, navigation-drawer

Using [Navigation Drawer](http://www.tutecentral.com/android-custom-navigation-drawer/) calling webpage inside webview. But when moving through the menu its reloading whole website and again and again. I just want to save the state of webpage from  where user left not from start of the webpage.

Thanks for any Help.

code:-

```
    public class Facebook extends Fragment {
    // this Fragment will be called from MainActivity
    public Facebook(){}

    private WebView webView ;
    private Bundle webViewBundle;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.facebook, container, false);
        webView = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.facebook);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);   
        webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true); 
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);
        if (webViewBundle == null) {
            try{
                webView.loadUrl("http://www.facebook.com");
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();}
        } else {

            webView.restoreState(webViewBundle);
            }
        return rootView;
        }
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        webViewBundle = new Bundle();
        webView.saveState(webViewBundle);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the Cache Mode to be LOAD_CACHE_ONLY after you loaded the website for the first time?

```
WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
webSettings.setCacheMode(LOAD_CACHE_ONLY);
```

Answer (score 0):

Before getting frustrated or pulling your hair out add this next to viewpager.

```
ViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);// three is my number of fragments.
```